# Using Numpy instead of loops

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have the following dummy data:

```
import numpy as numpy


x = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)
y = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)
x[::-1].sort()
y[::-1].sort()
tot_value = np.sum(y)

n_values = np.array([1, 2, 3])

final = np.sum((x[:, np.newaxis]**(1/n_values))*(y[:, np.newaxis]/tot_value))**n_values

final2 = [np.sum((x[:, np.newaxis]**(1/i))*(y[:, np.newaxis]/tot_value))**i for i in n_values]
```

My problem is that I want to use Numpy (`final`) to emulate the loop seen in `final2` due to speed when getting larger arrays ans stuff. But the output is not the same, and I have been trying different stuff, but I just can't seem to figure out how to do it, and if it is even possible ?

The output of `final` is:

```
[275.3622303   16.59404201  16.59404201]
```

Where it should be as in `final2`:

```
[6.7290539608469775, 7.0, 7.0]
```

Maybe I'm going blind on this, but I just haven't been able to see how to do it.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my mistake. That was supposed to be `n_values`. It has been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply using the array directly into the same expression and summing along the first axis -

```
i = n_values
out = np.sum((x[:, np.newaxis]**(1/i))*(y[:, np.newaxis]/tot_value),axis=0)**i
```

Another and a more performant one with `einsum` -

```
out = np.einsum('ij,ij->j',x[:, np.newaxis]**(1/i),y[:, np.newaxis]/tot_value)**i
```

And more with `matrix-multiplication` -

```
out = (y/tot_value).dot(x[:, np.newaxis]**(1/i))**i
```

Comment: Ah, so I was only missing the `axis=0` property. Well, there you go :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using broadcasting:

```
np.sum(
    (x[None, :] ** (1 / n_values[:, None])) * (y[None, :] / tot_value),
    axis=1
) ** n_values
```